# How do I save file input to local and then retrieve it back to another file input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I'm trying to make a multi-step form using HTML5 and javascript. What I'm trying to do is for each step, save form data to **localStorage** and then at the final step, retrieve the data back from localStorage and assign those data to hidden fields. For text data I have no problem doing that but for file input, I cannot save it to **localStorage** after file input field has been stringtified. I did some more research and came up with constructing a Blob object and then attach that Blob to a hidden file input but people say for security reasons, that is not possible. Any ideas on how I can do this or a different solution? I'm new to this.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$(document).on("click", ":submit", function(e) {
    var fileData = ($($file).val())
    var stringtified = JSON.stringify(fileData);
    localStorage.setItem('savedFile', stringtified);
});
```

Comment: You can't stringify binary file data. You can however base64 encode it to a string and store that, which the duplicate I marked covers. However note that you cannot put that file data back in to a file input as the browsers security measures prevent programmatic access to the file src.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have just read the duplicate but it looks like that's not what I want. I need a solution to reconstruct a file input from a previous form step. Is it possible to somehow duplicate the file input field data so that I can put that in another form?

Comment: `I need a solution to reconstruct a file input from a previous form step` Sorry, that's not possible. You could instead send the file as a base64 encoded string in a `<input type=hidden>` and then re-build it on the server.